# oval custom method validation - Pre condition

Tags: java, spring, validation, annotations, oval

I'm using Oval validation Fwk + Spring. I want to validate my Business logic method using annotations. I found a nice example in the Oval Page.
http://best-practice-software-engineering.ifs.tuwien.ac.at/repository/net/sf/oval/oval/1.61/tmp/docs/userguide.html#d4e489

for creating custom validations. But The provided example seems to work after the method is executed instead of before. Is there a way to achieve the same as the example but executed before?

here is my spring configuration.

```
<bean id="ovalGuardInterceptor" class="net.sf.oval.guard.GuardInterceptor" />

<bean class="org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.BeanNameAutoProxyCreator">
    <property name="proxyTargetClass" value="true" />
    <property name="beanNames" value="productGetBusinessLogic" />
    <property name="interceptorNames"><list><value>ovalGuardInterceptor</value></list></property>
</bean>
```

this is my check class

```
import net.sf.oval.Validator;
import net.sf.oval.configuration.annotation.AbstractAnnotationCheck;
import net.sf.oval.context.OValContext;

public class TestValidatorCheck extends AbstractAnnotationCheck<TestValidator> {
    public boolean isSatisfied(Object validatedObject, Object valueToValidate, OValContext context,    Validator validator) {
    if (valueToValidate == null)
        return true;
    String val = valueToValidate.toString();
    return val.equals(val.toUpperCase());
    }
}
```

This is my annotation class

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD})
@Documented
@net.sf.oval.configuration.annotation.Constraint(checkWith = TestValidatorCheck.class)
public @interface TestValidator {
 /**
 * Message to be used for the ConstraintsViolatedException
 * 
 * @see ConstraintsViolatedException
 */
 String message() default "must be upper case";
}
```

and this is how the method is annotated

```
@Override
@TestValidator
public ProductGetResponse getProductBulk(ProductGetKey productGetKey) throws ItemWrapperApiException {
```

Let me know what I'm missing here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The way you added the constraint annotation it declares it as constraint for the returning value.

For argument validation you need to specify the annotation directly at the method parameter to be validated, i.e.:

```
@Override
public ProductGetResponse getProductBulk(@TestValidator ProductGetKey productGetKey) throws ItemWrapperApiException
```